# Notes saved as a document?

Tags: macbook-pro, notes.app

Can I save a Note I created in my documents?  I don't know how to save a note to my documents folder or elsewhere.  I know there is Text Edit, but I have had it lose some important docs and don't trust it.  I would use it if someone could tell me how to find a doc that wasn't saved then computer shut down.  In Microsoft Word it auto saves.

Answer (score 2):

You can export Notes as a PDF in MacOS Sierra (10.12) or above. All you have to do is Choose File > Export as PDF.

Notes for macOS Sierra: Import or export notes

https://support.apple.com/kb/PH22616?locale=en_US

Or you can copy the text and paste it into a Pages or Word document.

Comment: Not an awful idea, but I think a little explanation is needed. Can you please add steps to export as PDF?